# View not what I want

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

So, I get the problem when I want to show the cart base on the store. I don't really know whether my database design is wrong or my controller.

**This is the database**

[image]

**Contoller**

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $itemuser = $request->user();
        $cartdetail = CartDetail::where('user_id', $itemuser->id)->get();
        $cart = Cart::where('user_id', $itemuser->id)->get();

        return view('customer.cart', [
            'title' => 'Cart',
            'carts' => $cart,
            'cartdetail' => $cartdetail
        ]);
    }
```

**View**

```
{{-- Cart --}}
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-9 my-3">
      <div class="table-responsive mb-4">
          @foreach ($carts as $cart)
             <h3>{{ $cart->Product->Store->name }}</h3>
             {{-- TABLE --}}
             <table class="table">
                {{-- HEAD --}}
              <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="border-0 p-3 h6 title" scope="col">
                                            Product
                    </th>
                    <th class="border-0 p-3 h6 title" scope="col">
                                            Price
                    </th>
                    <th class="border-0 p-3 h6 title ps-5" scope="col">
                                            Quantity
                    </th>
                    <th class="border-0 p-3 ps-4 h6 title" scope="col">
                                            Total
                    </th>
                 </tr>
              </thead>
              {{-- CONTENT --}}
              <tbody class="border-0">
                  @foreach ($carts as $cart)
                     <tr>
                         <td class="p-3 border-0">
                            <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                                <a class="reset-anchor d-block animsition-link" href="/products/{{ $cart->product->slug }}">
                                  @if($cart->product->image)
                                     <img src="img/admin_store/{{ $cart->product->image }}" width="70" />
                                  @else
                                     <img src="{{ asset('img/customer/img-1.png') }}" width="70" />
                                  @endif
                                </a>
                                <div class="ms-3">
                                    <a class="reset-anchor animsition-link title text-decoration-none" href="/products/{{ $cart->product->slug }}">{{ $cart->product->name }}</a>
                                </div>
                             </div>
                          </td>
                          <td class="p-3 align-middle border-0">
                              <p class="mb-0 small">Rp{{ number_format(($cart->product->price * ((100 - $cart->product->discount)/100)), 0,",",".") }}</p>
                          </td>
                          <td class="p-3 align-middle border-0">
                              <form action="/update_cart" method="POST">
                                                @csrf
                                   <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-5">
                                             <input type="hidden" name="cart" value="{{ $cart->id }}">
                                             <input type="number" name="quantity" value="{{ $cart->qty }}" class="w-100 ms-5" min="0" max="{{ $cart->product->stock }}">
                                         </div>
                                   </div>
                                   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-dark ms-5    mt-2" style="margin-right:20px">Update</button>
                                </form>
                             </td>
                             <td class="p-3 align-middle border-0">
                                 <p class="mb-0 small">Rp{{ number_format($cart->total_product, 0,",",".") }}</p>
                             </td>
                             <td class="p-3 align-middle border-0">
                                 <form action="/delete_cart" method="post">
                                                @csrf
                                      <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="{{ $cart->id }}">
                                      <a class="reset-anchor">
                                         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link">
                                                        <img src="{{ asset('img/customer/bx-trash.svg') }}" width="20">
                                         </button>
                                      </a>
                                   </form>
                               </td>
                            </tr>
                       @endforeach
                  </tbody>
              </table>
         @endforeach
     </div>
</div>
```

**This is the result**

[image: this product]
*note = store name, product and pictures are for study only

My expectation is that each cart contains products that match the store, but the result is that the product loops don't match the store. How to solve it?

Comment: You need to update your controller, `$cart` is getting all records by `user_id`. You need to group carts based on `store_id` and `user_id` together.

Comment: yes I try like this 
```$cart = Cart::where('user_id', $itemuser->id)->groupBy('user_id', 'store_id')->get();``` but the result still same

Comment: you are iterating `$carts` and inside that loop you are then iterating `$carts`, its cartception

Comment: then how to loop outside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why a cart would only have 1 product, usually a shopping cart has multiple items, but I guess `carts` is "cart items" in reality.

You can group this Collection of "carts" by the store name then you can iterate that Collection (which would be iterating the stores with the items from that store in each Collection) then you can iterate through the items you have grouped for each store:

In your Controller:

```
...
$carts = $cart->groupBy(fn ($i) => $i->Product->Store->name);
```

In your view:

```
@foreach ($carts as $store => $items)
    ...
    {{ $store }} // store name
    ...
    @foreach ($items as $item) // iterate each item that was grouped by store
        ...
        {{ $item->Product->name }}
        ...
    @endforeach
    ... Total Product {{ $items->sum('total_product') }} ...
@endforeach
```

[Laravel 9.x Docs - Collections - Available Methods -](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-groupby) `groupBy`

[Laravel 9.x Docs - Collection - Available Methods -](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-sum) `sum`

Comment: Sorry, ```$carts = $cart->groupBy(fn ($i) => $i->Product->Store->name);``` I don't understand the syntax, can you make it simple for the beginning like me?

Comment: PHP Arrow Functions (https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php) ... which is the same as `groupBy(function ($i) { return $i->Product->Store->name; })` using a regular anonymous function (https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) ... these are things you will have learn about

Comment: But, how I want to get total_product? Because I try, ```$carts->total_product * $carts->qty``` I get the error

Comment: you get "what" error?  and it wouldn't be `$carts` as that is the Collection of "carts" grouped by store not a `Cart` itself... you would need to be getting it from the current iteration for the second loop, `$item`, `$item->total_product * $item->qty`, since `$item` is a 'Cart` model instance

Comment: yes, but I want to display the total result per store and i make it outside ```foreach($items as $item)```

so, I try this ```dd($carts["Razer Flagship Store"][0]->total_product + $carts["Razer Flagship Store"][1]->total_product);``` and this work, but I can't display in view

Comment: `$items->sum('total_product')` ... https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-sum